# How to detect when there is an error reading DRM Widevine license in Exoplayer

Tags: exoplayer, drm, widevine

I have an application with videos DASH + DRM Widevine. In emulators and certain tv boxes there is an error when reading the license, and it does not play the protected content. What I want to achieve is that, if there is an error with the license, that some other function can be executed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Exoplayer supports listeners which you can use to listen for errors and react to them as you want - info is avaikable here:

- https://exoplayer.dev/doc/reference-v1/com/google/android/exoplayer/ExoPlayer.Listener.html#onPlayerError-com.google.android.exoplayer.ExoPlaybackException-

You can add listeners to your player instance:

```js
yourExoPlayerInstance.addListener(new Player.EventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPlayerError(ExoPlaybackException e) {
                    //Add you code to check the error type here 
                    //and take whatver actions you need
                }
});
```

Note that DRM errors from a DRM server can sometimes be vague and low on details. This is possibly to avoid attackers trying to learn how the DRM servers behaves (or because they forgot to add better errors reasons...).

Looking specifically at the case where content plays on a real device but not in the emulator - DRM systems on mobiles are usually strongly linked to HW on the device, using a HW root of trust.

When you run an app in an emulator that HW link is not there and some secure applications and operations like DRM will not work.

As an over-simplified, but hopefully useful illustration, if you can imagine that a decryption key is stored in some 'HW secured' memory on a real device, on an emulator this would have to be emulated in SW and it might be significantly easier to reverse engineer and hence discover the decryption key.

In reality emulators in some cases may be able to pass through these type of secure functions to the base platform they are running on, so you may find for some ecosystems and emulators it will work. However, even if it does you getting further away from how the app actually works on a real device, so it probably safest to test these type of use cases on real devices where possible.

Comment: The protected video works on all cell phones, but in emulators and some TV Box the screen remains black, as if it did not read the license, do you know why this happens?

Comment: @RichJ, see updated answer adding in notes on emulators.

Comment: Could you tell me how can I implement this in application? I don't have much experience with this..

Comment: It sounds like you actually already have it working in the application if it is running on cell phones.

Comment: I'm certainly not aware of a solution on an emulator that will properly play back the usual HW lined security levels typically used on Mobiles.